# How to get field count Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Question title is senseles ,I know it. But my problem seems to diffucult to explain.

I have a one table on phpmyadmin like this

```
+-----+-----+----
| id |tag |item|
+=====+=====+===
| 1 |  1  | 132|
+-----+-----+---
| 2 |  2  | 132|
+-----+-----+---
| 3 |  2  | 134|
+-----+-----+---  
| 4 |  1  | 135|
+-----+-----+---
```

I want to find count of RELATED items.

For instance item-132 has 1,2 tag values and item-134 has 2 tag values.  item-132 and item-134  has same 2 tag value. SO item-132 and item-134  has one  related  tag.

I want to get relation tags count like this ...

How can I set SQL query that get relation tag count in MySQL.

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output? I found the question a bit hard to follow.

Comment: The item repeating is a typo?

Answer (score 1):

A self join will get you started:

```
select t1.item item1, t2.item item2, etc
from table t1 join table t2 on t1.item <> t2.item
and t1.tag = t2.tag
where whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the tags only exist at most once per item, you can use a self join;

```
SELECT t2.item, COUNT(t2.id) cnt
FROM mytable t1 
JOIN mytable t2 
  ON t1.tag=t2.tag AND t1.item<>t2.item
WHERE t1.item = 132
GROUP BY t2.item
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8138e/1).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the relation count between 132 and 134, you might want to consider

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS relcount
FROM tablename AS aa
INNER JOIN tablename AS bb ON aa.tag=bb.tag
WHERE aa.item=132
AND bb.item=134
```

Comment: Thank you Eugen its very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tt t1 
JOIN tt t2 ON t1.tag=t2.tag 
WHERE t1.item = 132 
AND t2.item = 134;
```

Answer (score 0):

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ba36/6/0) This will give you the related tag and the item1 and item2 (items that have this related tag)

```
SELECT T1.tag,T1.item as item1,T2.item as item2
FROM yourTable T1
INNER JOIN yourTable T2
ON (T1.tag = T2.tag AND T2.item > T1.item)
```

then if you want a count, you can add the COUNT(T1.tag) and GROUP BY item1,item2 like ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ba36/7/0))

```
SELECT COUNT(T1.tag) as relatedCount,T1.item as item1,T2.item as item2
FROM yourTable T1
INNER JOIN yourTable T2
ON (T1.tag = T2.tag AND T2.item > T1.item)
GROUP BY item1,item2
```